# removing double backslash from string containing some of them

Tags: string, haskell, replace, backslash

I'm having trouble cause I can't define a function to do this:

Input: "(case (+ 5 5) ((4 9 1) 'd64)\\n((1 2) 'pepito)\\n((10) 'jorgito)"
Output: "(case (+ 5 5) ((4 9 1) 'd64)\n((1 2) 'pepito)\n((10) 'jorgito)"

I've tried this and many other, without success:

```
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Data.List (intersperse)
import Data.Char

replace :: String -> String -> String -> [String]
replace current next [] = []
replace current next xs = intersperse [chr 92] $ splitOn current xs
```

I know the last function is not well coded looking their arguments, but I tried to do a replace function for "all strings" but I can't by now.

Then, my parser can't work cause is something like this:

```
parseCaseResult :: Parser LispVal
parseCaseResult = do
    char '\''
    first <- (letter <|> symbol) --de momento será una String
    rest <- many (digit <|> letter <|> symbol)
    return $ String (first:rest)

parseCasePair :: Parser CasePair
parseCasePair = do
    list <- lexeme (char '(') >> (lexeme (char '(')) *> parseList <* (lexeme $ char ')')
    result <- lexeme $ parseCaseResult <* char ')'
    return (list, result)

parseCaseExpr :: Parser LispVal
parseCaseExpr = do
    lexeme $ char '('
    lexeme $ string "case"
    conditional_expr <- lexeme (char '(') *> parseList <* lexeme (char ')')
    -- armada en las nuevas líneas, solucionado con un parser más trabajado
    lista <- sepBy parseCasePair newline -- $ try (string "\\\\\n") <|> try (string "\n") <|> string "\r"
    return $ CaseExpr conditional_expr lista
```

New info:

[Complete code in github.com](https://github.com/freinn/libroshaskell/blob/master/write48/cap_5/ejercicio_3.hs)

Example that works in GHCi:

```
*Main> eval $ fromRight $ parse parseExpr "jaja" "(case (+ 5 5) ((4 9 1)   'd64\n((1 2) 'pepito\n((10) 'jorgito)"  
10 (4 9 1)
10 (1 2)
10 (10)
Right "jorgito"
```

But if I compile and run the `main` function, the code does not work I think because the parser doesn't match those `\\n`.

Sorry for the bad explanation in earlier versions of this question.

Comment: The escaping makes this a bit confusing. Are you looking for a function that turns a \ followed by an n into an actual newline character?

Comment: @DavidYoung Now it's edited and I think that is more clear. When I do `getArgs`, that getArgs give me a `String` with those `\\n`, so my parser can't parse that and my program fails.

Comment: Note that when you `print` a string that contains a single backslash,  Haskell will quote that backslash.   Are you sure that the string actually contains a double backslash,  or might it just have a `\n` in it?

The confusing thing about your question is that in Haskell syntax,  the first string contains a `\n`,  whereas the second contains a literal ascii newline character.

Comment: @lpsmith yes, I edit and include the link to github.com for you to see the entire code and some comments with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The needed function is:

```
foo :: String -> String
foo s = read $ "\"" ++ s ++ "\""
```

That achieves what I wanted, transform:

"(case (+ 5 5) ((4 9 1) 'd64)\\n((1 2) 'pepito)\\n((10) '789.456)"

into

"(case (+ 5 5) ((4 9 1) 'd64)\n((1 2) 'pepito)\n((10) '789.456)"

and now my parser is working like a charm